# ListView in android adds padding to headers same size as dividerHeight

Tags: android, listview, header, divider

I have a simple ListView in Android containing items, a headerView and a footerView. The headerView and footerView are added programatically to the ListView.

The xml for the ListView looks as follows:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="8dp"
    android:divider="@color/gray"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />
```

This gives a gray divider of 8dp between each listitem which is exactly what I want. The problem is that it also adds a padding between the headerView and the first listitem with the same color as the theme background (white in my case), the padding is also the same height as the dividerHeight (8dp).

I though that the property headerDividersEnabled="true" would take care of this, from the reference:

> android:headerDividersEnabled
>
> When set to false, the ListView will not draw the divider after each
>   header view. The default value is true.

If I set headerDividersEnabled="true", a grey 8dp divider between the listitem and headerView is drawn, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From what i got from your question is you are trying to hide the grey lines between items ,if so try this.

To remove the separator between items in the same ListView, here is the solution:

> getListView().setDivider(null); 
>   getListView().setDividerHeight(0);

developer.android.com # ListView

Or, if you want to do it in XML:

> android:divider="@null" 
>   android:dividerHeight="0dp"

Comment: Actually not, I do want the dividers between the items but not the divider between the item and the header. headerDividersEnabled="false" should fix the issue and indeed, the divider isn't shown between the item and header, but instead it adds padding between the item and header the same height as the dividerHeight.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in ListView

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

ListView will recycle its children as soon as they enter the padding area. The attribute clipToPadding only affects drawing

Comment: clipToPadding only seem to affect padding on the listview itself, not on padding between listitems and headerviews. Adding clipToPadding="false" didn't have any effect in my case.